# visual studio c++ won't recognize header file?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

This is my first time working with header files, and I have a source code and I'm trying to include my header file. The name of my header file is called `ccc_time.h` and i have `#include "ccc_time.h"` written in the beginning of my source file which is just called `source.cpp` however visual studio says no such header `ccc_time.h` file or directory exists.

The header file I did not write, it was assigned for my homework and i don't think I'm suppose to modify it. In the beginning of the header file, it reads

```
#ifndef CCC_TIME_H
#define CCC_TIME_H
```

I was also given another file called `ccc_time.cpp` and it has no problem recognizing the header file `ccc_time.h` but i can't seem to get my `source.cpp` to recognize that header file

Comment: You have to add `additional include directories` if it is not in the same folder as the .cpp file

Comment: then he also doesn't call "ccc_time.h" but <ccc_time.h> so probably this is in same dir

Comment: is the header `ccc_time.h` in the same directory as `source.cpp`?

Comment: is this file in same dir as your project?

Comment: @stardust no one is in a folder and the other is on desktop

Comment: copy file to your project dir and stay with #include "ccc_time.h" notation

Comment: yep. Put the header where `source.cpp` is then.

Comment: @imdumb you can mark my answer as actual answer

Answer (score 2):

if you want to add header with

```
 #include "ccc_time.h"
```

statement, then this header has to be in your project dir. So you may copy file to your project dir and stay with `#include "ccc_time.h"` notation.
Alternatively you might add path to folder where the file is located in your project "additional includes directory" and add then header with

```
 #include <ccc_time.h> statement.
```

you may also copy header to path already included, i.e to:

> ProgramFiles\MicrosoftVisualStudio11.0\VC\include

and again: add with      `#include <ccc_time.h>` statement.